# find view element im a specific area (iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view

how i can the element existing in a specific area in the view????
 example: get the exiting object existing between `x=(200,250) y=(130,150) px`

Answer (score 0):

See `-hitTest:withEvent:` on UIView.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

Just pass `nil` for the event, as indicated in the documentation.